# how to prevent TextWrangler to highlight syntax on .txt files?

Tags: macos, textwrangler

TextWrangler highlights syntax on my .txt files, how can I disable this?
It becomes really annoying when typing an apostrophe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just select *(none)* as the file's programming language at the bottom of the document window.

[image]

[image]

---

If TextWrangler automatically assigns a programming language to `.txt` files, check its preferences, and, if necessary, change or set the *(none)* language for `.txt` files:

[image]